# How do I speed up this SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
select min(a) from tbl where b > ?;
```

and it takes about 4 seconds on my mysql instance with `index(b, a)` (15M rows). Is there a way to speed it up?

Explain:

```
explain select min(parsed_id) from replays where game_date > '2016-10-01';

id:            1
select_type:   SIMPLE
table:         replays
partitions:    NULL
type:          range
possible_keys: replays_game_date_index,replays_game_date_parsed_id_index
key:           replays_game_date_parsed_id_index
key_len:       6
ref:           NULL
rows:          6854021
filtered:      100.00
Extra:         Using where; Using index
```

Index statement:

```
create index replays_game_date_parsed_id_index on replays (game_date, parsed_id);
```

Comment: Please post the execution plan.

Comment: Show us what `EXPLAIN select min(a) from tbl where b > ?;` outputs.

Comment: Buy more hardware.

Comment: you could create index for the game_date column

Comment: What you are asking for here is unclear.

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @JerryM. Can I create any new indexes or modify the query in such a way that it executes faster?

Comment: The query is choosing the index `replays_game_date_parsed_id_index`. Can you include its definition in the question?

Comment: I think this question should be asked and would be better answered on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No other index will help in this case. MySql must scan all entries in the index for dates > '2016-10-01', (6854021 records according to the explain result), it must take a while. You can calculate minimum values of `parsed_id` for all dates and then store a result of this query in separate table (kind of materialized view in other database), and then query this tiny table instead of the main huge table.

Comment: Throwing hardware at this won't help (assuming you already have enough RAM to keep what is needed in memory).

Comment: @RickJames nah it has only 1.7Gb ram for 160Gb database. Can't get more hardware as it is crowdfunded project and we are already out of budget.

Comment: @Poma - That's tight.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE replays`; maybe there are ways to shrink the table.  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: @RickJames https://gist.github.com/poma/beea1cd16a1029d52908cd17cf30f86b, buffer size is `671088640`. This is a managed SQL instance on Google Cloud.

Comment: @Poma - I added to my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the index MySQL is using is the right one. The query should be instantaneous since a SINGLE read from the index should return the result you want. I guess for this query MySQL's SQL optimizer is doing a very poor job.

Maybe you could rephrase your query to trick the SQL optimizer onto using a different strategy. Maybe you can try:

```
select parsed_id 
from replays
where game_date > '2016-10-01'
order by parsed_id
limit 1
```

Comment: Whoa, the second one worked! Can you explain why it is better than first?

Comment: It executes in 0.02sec

Comment: Waait, isn't this redundant ORDER BY causing it to just return the lowest date but not necessarily lowest id for it?

Comment: The second query in this Answer fails, based on Poma's comment.

Comment: Yes, that was true. The second query was wrong. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this version any faster?

```
select @mina
fro (select (@mina := least(@mina, a)) as mina
     from tbl cross join
          (select @mina := 999999) params
     where b > ?
    ) t
limit 1;
```

I suspect this won't make much difference, but I'm not sure what happens under the hood with such a large aggregation function running over an index.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help:  Change the query and add an index:

```
SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE b > ? ORDER BY a LIMIT 1;

INDEX(a, b)
```

Then, *if* a matching `b` occurs soon enough in the table, this will be faster than the other suggestions.

On the other hand, if the only matching `b` is near the end of the table, this will have to scan nearly all the index and be slower than the other options.

`a` needs to be first in the index.  By having both columns in the index, it becomes a "covering" index, hence a bit faster.

It *may* be that using my `SELECT`, together with *two* indexes will give the Optimizer enough to pick the better approach:

```
INDEX(a,b)
INDEX(b,a)
```

**Schema**

Adding either (or both) composite indexes should help.

Shrinking the table size is likely to help...

- `INT` takes 4 bytes.  Consider whether a smaller datatype would suffice for any of those columns.
- There are 3 dates (`DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`); do you need all of them?
- Is `fingerprint varchar(36)` a UUID/GUID?  If so, it could be packed into `BINARY(16)`.

640MB is tight -- check the graphs to make sure there is no "swapping".  (Swapping would be really bad for performance.)